# synchronize 3 threads to print sequential output

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I was asked this question in an interview. I was pretty clueless.
So I decided to learn some multithreading and hopefully find an answer to this question.

I need to use 3 threads to print the output: 01020304050607.....

1. Thread1: prints 0
2. Thread2: prints odd numbers
3. Thread3: prints even numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv1, cv2, cv3;

int count = 0;

void printzero(int end)
{
    while (count <= end)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        cv1.wait(lock);
        std::cout << 0 << " ";
        ++count;
        if (count % 2 == 1)
        {
            lock.unlock();
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
        else
        {
            lock.unlock();
            cv3.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void printodd(int end)
{
    while (count <= end)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        cv2.wait(lock);
        if (count % 2 == 1)
        {
            std::cout << count << " ";
            ++count;
            lock.unlock();
            cv1.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void printeven(int end)
{
    while (count <= end)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        cv3.wait(lock);
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << count << " ";
            ++count;
            lock.unlock();
            cv1.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int end = 10;

    std::thread t3(printzero, end);
    std::thread t1(printodd, end);
    std::thread t2(printeven, end);

    cv1.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

My solution seems to be in a deadlock situation. I'm not even sure if the logic is correct. Please help

Comment: In Printodd and Printeven you lock on the mutex and only unlock if the  if condition is true - what if it's false ?

Comment: Why not just put the while loop in the main function and notify the appropriate thread (and wait for it to finish printing)? That would make the sequencing mechanism much easier as it would be impemented in one place only (the main function). Or is there a requirement, you didn't mention, that forbids such solution?

Comment: @auburg if the condition is false, Wouldn't unique_lock go out of scope and automatically be released?

Comment: Well why call unlock at all then ?

Comment: @auburg I tried adding an `else` condition with an `unlock()`. Doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @LorenzZhao I will try your suggestion. There is no such requirement

Comment: Right off the bat, your code exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race. You are reading `count` outside of the lock, possibly concurrently with another thread modifying it.

Comment: It's not possible to deadlock with only one mutex. You just failing to notify cv, and waiting forever. This is because some notify should happen after *every* wait(). You counting incorrectly in odd/even, you need to do `count += 2;`

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. Here is what you need to do in order to make it work:

1. Revise your `while (count <= end)` check. Reading `count` without synchronization is undefined behavior (UB).
2. Use a proper predicate with [`std::condition_variable::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait). Problems of your code without predicate:

   - If `notify_one` is called *before* `wait` then the notification is lost. In the worst case, `main`'s call to `notify_one` is executed before the threads start running. As a result, all threads may wait indefinitely.
   - [Spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) may disrupt your program flow. See also [cppreference.com on `std::condition variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).
3. Use `std::flush` (just to be sure).

I played around with your code quite a lot. Below you find a version where I applied my suggested fixes. In addition, I also experimented with some other ideas that came to my mind.

```
#include <cassert>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// see the `std::mutex` for an example how to avoid global variables

std::condition_variable cv_zero{};
std::condition_variable cv_nonzero{};

bool done = false;
int next_digit = 1;
bool need_zero = true;

void print_zero(std::mutex& mt) {
  while(true) {// do not read shared state without holding a lock
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mt);
    auto pred = [&] { return done || need_zero; };
    cv_zero.wait(lk, pred);
    if(done) break;

    std::cout << 0 << "\t"
              << -1 << "\t"// prove that it works
              << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n"// prove that it works
              << std::flush;

    need_zero = false;

    lk.unlock();
    cv_nonzero.notify_all();// Let the other threads decide which one
                            // wants to proceed. This is probably less
                            // efficient, but preferred for
                            // simplicity.
  }
}

void print_nonzero(std::mutex& mt, int end, int n, int N) {
// Example for `n` and `N`: Launch `N == 2` threads with this
// function. Then the thread with `n == 1` prints all odd numbers, and
// the one with `n == 0` prints all even numbers.
  assert(N >= 1 && "number of 'nonzero' threads must be positive");
  assert(n >= 0 && n < N && "rank of this nonzero thread must be valid");

  while(true) {// do not read shared state without holding a lock
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mt);
    auto pred = [&] { return done || (!need_zero && next_digit % N == n); };
    cv_nonzero.wait(lk, pred);
    if(done) break;

    std::cout << next_digit << "\t"
              << n << "\t"// prove that it works
              << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n"// prove that it works
              << std::flush;

// Consider the edge case of `end == INT_MAX && next_digit == INT_MAX`.
// -> You need to check *before* incrementing in order to avoid UB.

    assert(next_digit <= end);
    if(next_digit == end) {
      done = true;
      cv_zero.notify_all();
      cv_nonzero.notify_all();
      break;
    }

    ++next_digit;
    need_zero = true;

    lk.unlock();
    cv_zero.notify_one();
  }
}

int main() {
  int end = 10;
  int N = 2;// number of threads for `print_nonzero`

  std::mutex mt{};// example how to pass by reference (avoiding globals)

  std::thread t_zero(print_zero, std::ref(mt));

// Create `N` `print_nonzero` threads with `n` in [0, `N`).
  std::vector<std::thread> ts_nonzero{};
  for(int n=0; n<N; ++n) {
// Note that it is important to pass `n` by value.
    ts_nonzero.emplace_back(print_nonzero, std::ref(mt), end, n, N);
  }

  t_zero.join();
  for(auto&& t : ts_nonzero) {
    t.join();
  }
}
```